# How to find name start with '%' in sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to search name which start with **'%'** like **'%smit'** in oracle sql

i have tried with escape **'%\%'** but not able to find..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Oracle that you *are* using an escape character:

```
where name like '\%%' escape '\'
```

Anything in the search pattern after the character specified through the `escape` option will be treated "as is". So the above searches for any value that starts with the character `%`. The second `%` is again treated as a regular wildcard (because it's not prefixed with the escape character)

You can also choose a different escape character:

```
where name like '#%%' escape '#'
```

This is nothing Oracle specific, this is how the LIKE operator is defined in the SQL standard

Comment: yes its working                                                                                                      select * from emp1 where ename like '\%%' escape '\';